# In Oracle SQL query below why i am getting output like this ? Please tell me the logic behind

Tags: sql, oracle

Table 1 Employee table

[image: This is EMP table with 14 rows]

Table 2 Dept table

[image: This is Dept table with 4 rows]

I wanted to filter employees who are working in LOC dallas and chicago

I know the correct query should be like below , we should use brackets (LOC = 'DALLAS' OR LOC = 'CHICAGO')

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMP E, DEPT D 
WHERE E.DEPTNO  =  D.DEPTNO 
AND (LOC = 'DALLAS' OR LOC = 'CHICAGO')
```

Here 11 rows were coming in output

---

But , i just wanted to see what would happen if we don't put brackets like below

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMP E, DEPT D 
WHERE E.DEPTNO  =  D.DEPTNO 
AND LOC = 'DALLAS' OR LOC = 'CHICAGO'
```

Here 19 rows were coming in output

I want to understand basically how this query is getting executed.

Comment: `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`, so your second query is like `WHERE (E.DEPTNO  =  D.DEPTNO AND LOC = 'DALLAS') OR LOC = 'CHICAGO'`

Comment: You should stop using cross products and use ANSI JOIN to specify the relationship between the tables.